# React state empty when changing route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        setMenu: (window.location.pathname.split("/")[1] == '') ? '/' : window.location.pathname.split("/")[1]
    };

    this.menuItens = new Menu();
    this.menuItens = this.menuItens.Itens;
};
```

and in my sidebar menu item:

```
<NavLink tag={Link}
         to={item.path}
         title={item.title}                                                  
         onClick={this.setMenu}                                                  
         className={(this.state.setarMenu === item.title) ? 'active' : ''}>

        <span>{item.nome}</span>
</NavLink>
```

I'm trying to change the state by calling a function:

```
setMenu = (event) => {
    this.setState({setarMenu: event.target.title});
};
```

But unfortunately, sometimes the state doesn't change because the window.location.pathname came empty.

Anybody have a clue why this happens?

Comment: I assume you haven't written `setarMenu` in your actual code?

Comment: When do you feel the `window.location.pathname` is coming empty? Is it during the beginning of the application?

Comment: first of all fix the typo in his.menuItens = this.menuItens.Itens; it should be items and not itens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, simply remove the  tag of the NavLink component of Reactstrap and it works fine.

Appears that, with the span tag inside the NavLink, the component sometimes return only  with no attributes like title={item.title} instead of  with attributes that I need to "set menu" (setState).

BTW: In PT-BR we write "item" no "iten", that's why sometimes we "misspelled" it.

Thank you guys anyway.